# Configure email in aimeos laravel

Tags: php, email, laravel-5, configuration, e-commerce

I'm doing a project on an e-commerce site (which is using Laravel) that customize on Aimeos. However I was stuck in email configuration, it couldn't send email while registering users.

Note that I have configure this in `myShop.php` and also set cronjobs

```
'email' => array(
    'from-email' => 'demo@aimeos.org',
    'from-name' => 'Demo shop',
)
```

cronjobs

`* * * * * php /Users/hakfonglim/Documents/laravel/aimeos/aimeos-laravel/myshop/artisan aimeos:jobs "customer/email/account"`

Answer (score 0):

Did you changed the config/shop.php file and added it in the array structure as described in the docs?

https://aimeos.org/docs/Laravel/Configure_cronjobs#Configuration

Comment: I did pretty much everything on these document but some how i still got no email when i try to register new users.
but in these document i just wonder how Aimeos could send and email to other by only the  from-email parameter it supposed to have full credential of the email address.

Comment: You should post your question in the Aimeos forum (https://aimeos.org/help). There are more people that may help you with your problem